Changing primary replication config in standby node
I want to change the primary information to new primary node in standby postgresql node. I have this:
# In standby server
psql -At -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -p $PGPORT -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET primary_conninfo TO 'host=$1 port=$2 user=$REPLICA_USER password=$REPLICA_PASS';" 
psql -At -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -p $PGPORT -c "SELECT pg_reload_conf();"

But I have got this error:
2024-06-20 16:37:35.701 CEST [110] FATAL:  could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  replication slot "replicaf68dfca78cbbbc24b0b7bdda531449c0" does not exist

replicaf68dfca78cbbbc24b0b7bdda531449c0 is the slot name used in the old primary replication.
Which are the best practice to do this?

First copy the slot from old primary node to new primary node before using alter command.Now before connecting to new primary node make sure that starting from  slots's restart_lsn containing WAL_file all the required wal files are  present in new primary node.This check is important because it guarantees required wal files are present in new primary node after changing the primary_conninfo.
Also there can be scenario when old primary node is not availabe(crashed),then copy the slot initially to expected new primary node and periodically advance the slot in expected new primary node using pg_replication_slot_advance function by providing latest lsn from old primary node which advances the restart_lsn of slot present in expected primary node.
